# Iterative processes on uncountable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say we have a set $S$ for which the the property $\varphi$ is true, i.e. $\varphi(S)\equiv \top$, a  surjective function $f: S\to T$ and a theorem
$$ M\text{ is a set}, x\in M, \varphi(M)\equiv \top  \implies \varphi\big(\left(M\setminus\{x\}\right)\cup\{f(x)\}\big)\equiv \top$$

In other words, we can just iteratively, element for element, change $S$ into $M$.

If $S$ is finite, this is a trivial application of induction; If $S$ is countably infinite, we can yield $T$ as the limit of the process.

But how exactly does one argue if $S$ is uncountable?

Comment: If you can well-order it, you can argue by transfinite induction; you have to be careful with your limit ordinals, though, because what you have does not seem to provide that if $\varphi(M_i)\equiv \mathsf{T}$ for all $i$, then $\varphi(\cup_i M_i)\equiv \mathsf{T}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin But isn't it that any set can be well-ordered?

Comment: Depends on your axioms. But still, with an uncountable set you are going to have limit ordinals involved, and the “one-at-a-time” process won’t let you pass to the limit.

Comment: Note that saying "the limit of the process" does not actually explain or justify anything about the countably infinite case.  In particular, it is not actually valid to deduce $\varphi(T)$ is true in that case from just what you have assumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not even true in the countably infinite case.

Consider the case where $S$ is the positive integers, $T$ is the negative integers, $f\colon S\to T$ maps $n$ to $-n$, and $\varphi$ applies to subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ and is given by “has a minimum under the usual order of $\mathbb{Z}$”.

Clearly, $S$ has a minimum. If you have a subset $M$ of the integers that has a minimum, and you replace a single element of $M$ with its negative, the resulting set will still have a minimum, because it will be a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is bounded below, hence has a minimum.

However, it is not true that $f(S) = T$ has a minimum.  So even though you can replace any finite number of numbers with their negatives and still get a set with a minimum, you can’t get all the way to the countably infinite $S$; let alone to an uncountable set.

Comment: Thank you for the counter-example! How would I have to modify my statement for it to hold?

Comment: @Sudix: I don’t think it will; in general, one simply cannot pass from “I can do it for any finite number of things” to “I can do it for infinitely many things.”